# spark sql: select rows where column of DecimalType has larger scale than a numer

Tags: apache-spark-sql, scale, bigdecimal

I have a dataframe that has colum of datatype DecimalType(38,10). Not all values have 10 decimal digits. I want to select those rows that have a scale bigger than 4 (after removing the trailing zeros).

Is there a way to do that?

In pseudo code something like `ds.select(col1, col2).where(col3.hasScale >4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could do it:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;

val maxScale = 10

val decimalType = DataTypes.createDecimalType(38, maxScale)

val data = Seq(
  Row(BigDecimal.decimal(3.302302)),
  Row(BigDecimal.decimal(3.4434)),
  Row(BigDecimal.decimal(4.32)),
  Row(BigDecimal.decimal(4.230240505)),
  Row(BigDecimal.decimal(7.302)),
  Row(BigDecimal.decimal(4.34444))
)

val schema = List(
  StructField("number", decimalType, true)
)

val df = spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data),
  StructType(schema)
)

df.show()

val decimalScale = udf((n: Double) => {
  Stream.range(0, maxScale + 1).map { s => 
    val multiplier = scala.math.pow(10, maxScale)
    val modulus = scala.math.pow(10, maxScale - s)
    (s, n * multiplier % modulus)
  }.find(_._2 == 0).get._1
})

df.filter(decimalScale(col("number")) > 4).show()
```

Comment: That works. I was thinking a simpler way or maybe a function was already in place that I was missing somehow. Probably should convert this into a UDF.

Comment: I modified my answer to use a UDF. The UDF simply returns the scale, so you can then compare it against any value that you'd like to.

Comment: @GregHill, does this fit your use case?